# Search using the MX Range Slider plugin

Tags: search, range

I have a super table field (`scoreRanges`) that has two columns: [mx range slider](https://github.com/MaxLazar/mx-rangeslider-craftcms) (`range`) & rich text (`summary`). Some entries can have multiple rows:

[image]

I'm trying search a row in that field that has a range between a certain value. MX range slider saves data ranges to the database text field like `9;20` which is a range from `9` to `20`.

Does anyone have an idea of how to search for a row between a certain range? So far I have tried this which returns no results.

```
{% for range in profile.scoreRanges.range('and', '>=' ~ result.points, '<=' ~ result.points) %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

On the template side, I have variables like `{{ range.range.from }}` & `{{ range.range.to }}` to use.

## Update

Currently not ideal. Using a conditional to filter the correct row, but will work now `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

```
{% for range in profile.scoreRanges %}
    {% if result.points >= range.range.from and result.points <= range.range.to %}
        <p><span class="label label-warning">Range:</span> {{ range.range.from }} - {{ range.range.to }}<br> <span class="label label-primary">Your Score:</span> <b>{{ result.points }}</b></p>
        {{ range.summary }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way the plugin is currently written, it won't support your initial syntax. i.e. `range('and', '>=' ~ result.points, '<=' ~ result.points)`.  It would need to override [BaseFieldType's modifyElementsQuery](https://craftcms.com/classreference/fieldtypes/BaseFieldType#modifyElementsQuery-detail) to support that syntax.

You could slightly improve on your solution by using the [MN Break and Continue](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/mn-break-and-continue) plugin to at least break out of the for loop once a match is found.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input and pointers Brad. I'll use your solution as a temporary band-aid. Going to put in a FR with Max to see if he will add the `modifyElementsQuery()` method.